# How can i use jQuery/AJAX to load a page and send data?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I will try to word this as clearly as possible.

So I have a link which upon a click will submit some data to my database.

```
<a href='' id='likePost' ><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i></a>
```

So when this link is clicked, I would want some data that is relevant to the "post" sent to the PHP file which will then process to the MySQL database.

The current jQuery I have is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(function(){
    $("#likePost").click(function(event){ 
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"functions/likePost.php",
            data:"post=<?= $post['unique_post_id'] ?>",
            success:function(html){
                alert("Liked post = success")
            }

        });
});
// ]]></script>
```

One thing at this stage that i'd like to point out is each post has a unique ID which can be called upon with `$post['unique_post_id']`.

My PHP file code is:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once("../global.php");

$unique = $_POST['post'];

/* FIND USER ID OF TARGET (OWNER OF POST) */
$findID = $connection->query("SELECT userid FROM posts WHERE unique_post_id='{$unique}'");
$id = $findID->fetch_assoc();

/* INSERT LIKE INTO DB */
$time = time();
$qry = $connection->query("INSERT INTO posts_likes (id, from_user_id, target_user_id, unique_post_id, time) VALUES (NULL, '{$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}','{$id}','{$unique}', '{$time}')");

?>
```

However none of this works. I'm pretty sure that there's something wrong with the AJAX code. Any idea's how I can achieve this?

Just as a quick summary, what I need is:

> CLICK --> TRIGGER AJAX CODE? --> LOAD PHP FILE WITH ADDITIONAL DATA ATTACHED (unique post id) --> PHP FILE INSERTS QUERY.

Hope I've been as clear as possible, thanks in advance :)

(If I seem nooby, my age might be a reason: 15)

Comment: your page is reloading when you click the link, and it's probably happening too fast for the ajax to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You should open up your browser console and see what errors are being thrown. 
Base off of what script I've read your data definition looks wrong, I believe it wants an object like

```
$.ajax({
    data: { post : '23', id: '32' }
});
```

And you should prevent the default click from reloading your page by using no href attribute or `href="#"` or by using

```
$('element').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```